# Collation error during exporting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to copy data from one database to another with built-in export tool.
but I get this error:

```
Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "Name" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1250 and 1252) are specified for it.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)



Error 0xc02020f4: Data Flow Task 1: The column "CatalogNo" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1250 and 1252) are specified for it.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Device" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task 1: One or more component failed validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task 1: There were errors during task validation.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I know that error:

```
Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Device" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Is probably caused by wrong order of copying data. ( FK)

And the first two errors are caused by not the same collation in the columns.

Databases and tables have same collation. How can I set columns to use table default collation?
I tried to change this manually but in collation list on the column lvl there is no collation set for table and db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I change It manually in `Design` ->`Collation`->`Restore default`
after that I copied all the data.